# Cannot get log_min_duration_statement to work

Tags: postgresql, logging, configuration, postgresql-8.4

I have been googling for more than 2 hours, but I am really stuck with this one.
I want PostgreSQL (I am using version 8.4 on Debian) to start logging slow queries only.

To that extend I use the following configuration in `postgresql.conf`:

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_min_messages = log
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
log_duration = on
log_line_prefix = '%t '
log_statement = 'all'
```

The rest of the configuration is all on default settings (commented out). The logging works, but it logs all statements, even the ones below the threshold of 1000 (ms). If I do a 'show all' I see that all settings are in effect. I also tried restarting Postgres.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 25):

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

instructs the server to log all statements, simple as that.
In addition:

```
log_duration = on
```

also instructs the server to log all statements, including duration info.
Change that to:

```
log_statement = none
log_duration = off
```

No quotes needed. Or comment them out and reload.
Then no statement will logged, except those running longer than 1000 ms - instructed by:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
```

It's [all in the excellent manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT).

Comment: can postgres log only queries longer than threshold with duration?

Comment: any insight into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786949/duration-logged-but-not-the-statement-postgresql-are-there-any-specific-quer

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
log_line_prefix = '%t %p %r %d %u '### more context
log_statement = 'ddl' ### log schema changes
```